# insert multiple row in sql database with php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to insert multiple row in `sql` with php, after checking few conditions.

The condition is, if 'cat' and 'preview' is not null then row one will be submitted and if 'cat','preview','cat2','preview2' is not null then two row will submitted with first row's value 'cat' and'preview and 2nd row's value 'cat2' and 'preview2'.

i tried these code, but i see -  Undefined variable: `sql`

#### whats wrong with my condition?

```
else if(isset($cat)and ($cat!=="") and isset($preview)and ($preview=="") and 
(isset($cat2))and ($cat2!=="") and (isset($preview2))and ($preview2!==""))
  { 
   $sql = "INSERT INTO files (cat, preview, file, art) VALUES 
         ('".$cat."','".$preview."','".$file."','".$art."')
         ('".$cat2."','".$preview2."','".$file2."','".$art2."')";
  }
```

Comment: @Swister did my answer worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

your code just had query mistake that you wanted to insert two row in just one insert command.use this code that seperates the insert commands :

```
else if(!empty($cat) and !empty($preview) and
!empty($cat2) and !empty($preview2))
{  
$sql = "INSERT INTO files (cat, preview, file, art) VALUES 
                      ('".$cat."','".$preview."','".$file."','".$art."');";
$sql .= " INSERT INTO files (cat, preview, file, art) VALUES ('".$cat2."','".$preview2."','".$file2."','".$art2."');";
}
```

Comment: Please explain your answer.

Comment: it showsError: INSERT INTO files (cat, preview, file, art) VALUES('Dj Vol 2','Dj song 1','file.mp3','') INSERT INTO files (cat, preview, file, art) VALUES ('Dj Vol 2','Dj song 2','file2.mp3','#2')
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO files (cat, preview, file, art) VALUES ('Dj Vol 2','Dj song 2','file' at line 1

Comment: @Swister i edited the code use it and let me know the results

Comment: `some query mistakes` .....please avoid such statements, rather, you should have mentioned *what* the mistake was....assume -1 for your answer!

Comment: Error: INSERT INTO files (cat, preview, file, art) VALUES ('Dj Vol 2','Dj song 1','file.mp3','<see here>'); INSERT INTO files (cat, preview, file, art) VALUES ('Dj Vol 2','Dj song 2','file2.mp3','#2');
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO files (cat, preview, file, art) VALUES ('Dj Vol 2','Dj song 2','file' at line 1

Comment: @Swister so the query insert data in database...but not saving $art.right?is $art String? is the art field in database varchar?

Comment: now i can see the following error : Error: INSERT INTO files (cat, preview, file, art) VALUES ('Dj Vol 2','Dj song 1','file.mp3','#'); INSERT INTO files (cat, preview, file, art) VALUES ('Dj Vol 2','Dj song 2','file2.mp3','#2');
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO files (cat, preview, file, art) VALUES ('Dj Vol 2','Dj song 2','file' at line 1

Comment: @Swister could you give me structure dump of your table?

Comment: files

Column Type Null Default Links to Comments
id (Primary) int(11) No       
cat text Yes  NULL     
preview text Yes  NULL     
file text Yes  NULL     
art text Yes  NULL

Answer (score 0):

Insert query with `;` is not one query...

For example

```
Insert into mytable (a,b,c) values (1,2,3); 
Insert into mytable (a,b,c) values (4,5,6); 
Insert into mytable (a,b,c) values (7,8,9);
```

is not one query, this is 3 insert queries.

That is mean when insert values (4,5,6) have error, values (1,2,3) query is successed....

We want if one row failed, all insert query fail.

Therefore, we don't write insert query with `;`

Example query:

```
Insert into mytable values(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9);
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally think that the logic you have with your conditions may need rethinking. For instance, if you save your values into arrays, you can automate this process:

```
// Save first values
$sqlArgs[]  =   array($cat,$preview,$file,$art);
// Save second values
$sqlArgs[]  =   array($cat2,$preview2,$file2,$art2);
// Loop through each row.
foreach($sqlArgs as $key => $array) {
    // If the `cat` or the `preview` empty, skip
    if(!empty(trim($array[0])) && !empty(trim($array[1])))
        $sql[]  =   "'".implode("','",$array)."'";
}
// If the sql has rows continue
if(!empty($sql)) {
    // Build the statement rows with implode() of values.
    // This assumes these are not user-input values or that you have
    // thoroughly sanitized the values.
    $statement  =   "INSERT INTO `files` (`cat`,`preview`,`file`,`art`) VALUES (".implode("),(",$sql).")";
    // Preview statement 
    print_r($statement);
}
```

This approach will take care of 0,1, or 2 inserts (or more if necessary) based on the two keys `cat` & `preview` being filled.

Comment: it worked @Rasclatt... can you say what to do for three or more rows?

Comment: It is hard to say because you don't have the rest of the code so I don't know how you assign the `$cat` or `$preview` or `$cat2` or `$preview2`. It would be easy though. Just make make more rows in the `$sqlArgs` array.

Comment: If you feel the question has been answered make sure to check off the answer that helped the most so others don't keep coming back thinking it's still open. Cheers!